# Building <select> in Access form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm a mySQL dev working with a lawyer who is an amateur MS Access user.

Current Access has a

- Organization table with id and name
- Person table with id and first_name, last_name, and job title
- Bridging table referencing foreign keys for Org and Person

The relationships are understood in Access and bridging  table functions correctly.  The table is populated (I believe) by the following query:

```
SELECT TB_BoardMembers.ID, TB_BoardMembers.First, TB_BoardMembers.Last, TB_BoardMembers.Occupation, TB_BoardMembersLINK.Person, TB_BoardMembersLINK.Entity, TB_BoardMembersLINK.Role, TB_BoardMembersLINK.start, TB_BoardMembersLINK.end
FROM TB_BoardMembers LEFT JOIN TB_BoardMembersLINK ON TB_BoardMembers.ID = TB_BoardMembersLINK.Person
ORDER BY TB_BoardMembers.Last;
```

Lawyer needs to add an element for looking up unique Person in the form which creates the bridging table rows.  Ideally this would be a  with Last, First - job title for each Person.  She is trying to get interns to populate the database.

I don't know Access at all or the Access terms for these elements.  Anyone have suggestions or links to docs explaining how to do this in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resource explains how to create the list/combo box.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-list-box-combo-box-or-drop-down-list-box-HP005240581.aspx

It does not mention that memo fields are not eligible as possible fields in the Lookup and that is worth noting if you are (like me) unfamiliar with Access.

A list box, combo box, or drop-down list box can be a bound or unbound control, and it can look up values in a fixed list or in a table or query. To create a bound list box, combo box, or drop-down list box that looks up values in a table or query, make sure the form or data access page is based on a record source that includes a foreign key field or Lookup field.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to come up with some solution without exact knowledge of the bridging table scheme, but you as mySQL-Developer can try the following:

1. MS Access supports both inner and outer joins in SQL queries, as well as nested queries -- why not to write a view (called "Query" in MS Access) that would pool all necessary information into a flat table?
2. Upon completing step 1 you can use the MS Access scalar function DLookup() to get the exact value from the table, or again just use DoCmd.RunSQL("your sql") directly in VBA code to fetch the information you need..

If you give me some more data I can probably provide you with VBA or SQL code...

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I have located and added the SQL that (I believe) is used to manage/update the bridging table  TB_BoardMembersLINK.  I'm more than a bit lost in Access.

Answer (score 0):

Does this resource help

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/CH001071392.aspx